# How to select DISTINCT using WHERE and OR

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am new to php and I have searched Google, other forums, this web site and looked at several books but cannot see how to do this. Please do not castigate me for my ignorance. I want to select distinct entries from a field (category) based on criteria from another field (code) and then display a drop down list containing the distinct categories. The field named 'code' contains one of three data values, being 1, 2, or 4. I only want to select the distinct category if the code field has '2' or '4', but not if it contains the value '1'.

I have tried several ways of doing this but I just get a confirmation that the database connection worked with a drop down box below it that has no content.

My current code after many trials is:

```
if ( ! $_POST['submit'] )
    {
        // form not submitted, so display form to get input from user

        echo '<form method="post" id="form_id" action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '">';
        try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=gosdirect", $username, $password);
        $code2 = '2';
        $code4 = '4';
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM directory WHERE code =$code2 OR code =$ode4     ORDER BY category ASC");
        $sql->execute();
        // display message if connection is OK
        echo ' Connected to database<br />';
        echo 'I am looking for local: <select name="category">';
        while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        $category = $row['category'];
        echo '<option value="' . $category . '">' . $category . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        // close the database connection
        $dbh = null;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        echo '<input id="form_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="search" /></form>';
        ?>
```

If I just use the line:

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM directory ORDER BY category ASC");
```

I do get the drop down box populated with the category names, but it also includes categories that have a value of '1' in the 'code' field and I don't want that, so I am assuming there is something fundamentally wrong with my 'SELECT request.

Here is an image of what I get:

[image: screen shot]
<sub>(source: [wigweb.biz](http://www.wigweb.biz/gosport-error.jpg))</sub>

I would appreciate any help on this.

Many Thanks

Tog Porter

Comment: What's the data type of `code` field?

Comment: Pretty confusing description.

Comment: In your statment you did write `$ode4` instead of `$code4`.

Comment: code field is VARCHAR

Comment: Oh yes, what an idiot I am. changing $ode4 to $code4 appears to work.  Thank you so much @H Lallianmawia. I have spent so much time on this.

Comment: but if your code could be something like '231' then it has 1 in it and also will be accepted, check my answer if you want to exclude them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matches the codes which have 2 or 4 in and exclude those which have 1 in them

```
SELECT DISTINCT category 
FROM directory 
Where (code like '%2%' or code like '%4%') and not  (code like '%1%')
ORDER BY category ASC
```

Also if you want to use a variable in the sql for a `varchar` filed surround it with quote as `'$code2'`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here: `code =$ode4`, it should be `code = $code4` and don't forget to include quotes (`'`) around `$code2` and around `$code4` since `code` field is a varchar

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM directory WHERE code = '$code2' OR code = '$code4'     ORDER BY category ASC");
```

Comment: I have experimented and it works with or without the quotes around the $code4 and $code2, although I don't know why.

Comment: That's because `$code2` or `$code4` only contains numerical characters. If `$code2` or `$code4` contains any non numerical characters without the quotes you'll get an error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the additional infomation. I used to do a lot of work in VBScript for asp pages with Microsoft Access but now I have moved to a host using php and mysql I have a massive learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM directory WHERE code != 1 ORDER BY category ASC");
```

Hope this will work. THnx

Comment: He is asking about 1st SQL query

Comment: Yes, that works too. i had no idea there would be so many different ways of achieving the same result.